# Intellij idea compiles but displays lots of errors of missing dependencies on editor

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using ultimate 2019.3

I am getting this weird thing that it shows lots of compilation errors on depnedenceis such as Spring, Vertx, Guava and stuff like this, but `gradle clean build` and `cmd + F9` works fine.

I tried stuff I found here:

- invalidate caches and restart
- delete both `.m2` and `.gradle/cahces`
- delete `.idea` (didn't find any `*.iml`
- delete the repository and clone it again from GIT, importing it again to IntelliJ.
- project structure -> set to Java 1.8 and checked structure and libraries - nothing out of the ordinary.
- installed plugin - choose runtime and set IntelliJ to run on Java 1.8

nothing worked!

Maybe its JDK issue? I see my java -version returns 1.8 but IntelliJ runs with JDK 11.

I am completely lost and have no idea what to do.

Please help.

Regards,
Ido

Comment: Make sure you are not using JetBrains Runtime for compilation in IntelliJ IDEA. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html . However, if IDE build works without errors, but the editor displays errors, it's probably some caches problem. Try with https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/ and see if it helps.

Comment: thanks but didn't work. 
I didn't try the 2020 as I don't like versions that are not yet fully released

Comment: Please contact support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new with the sample project and the logs attached (Help | Compress Logs and Show in ...). Also provide the screenshot of the errors.

Comment: Note that you don't need to configure IntelliJ IDEA to run on JDK 1.8, it's not related to the JDK used to build your project.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it like this:

- I deleted .gradle/cahces
- I removed IntelliJ 2019.3
- I also deleted my local repository

Tried to remove all old installations/version/repos.

- Downloaded and installed 2020.1
- git cloned my reposotory again
- imported my project

**And it works !! **

I hanve no idea why... 
maybe the new version.
maybe its the uninstall and remove all caches and versions.

Thanks to all of you who helped me.

Regards,
Ido